# mysql query to count white spaces or words from entire row

Tags: php, mysql

in my database one table is there with say name as tableA.the structure of table is given here

```
id      from     message
1       23       hi how are you
2       65       hey whats going on
3       74       enjoying the vacation with family
4       23       here in Australia its chilly season
5       74       hey sam whats the plan for tomorrow
```

see id is auto-increment.from column says which user is sending message and the message column consists of messages . i want to know which users has sent how many words .so i have to first count the words from row then i have to search the entire column and find where there is repetiotion and add the words for that particular user.in my example you can see that two places from 23 and 74 is coming. i want my output as

```
    from       nos
    23         10
    65         4 
    74         12
```

here you can see that 23 is coming in two rows so  i have added the no of words of two rows like that 74  is also coming in two rows .please guide

Comment: why are you doing this when it is already in the database? i would say do it before it gets inserted.

Comment: @SandeepRajoria No he needs the complete count of words per each "from" column.

Comment: @ i want all words to be counted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can count words by this query-

```
Select length('string')-length(replace('string',' ',''))+1;
```

For your table you can do it as

```
Select *,(length(message)-length(replace(message,' ',''))+1) from table_name
```

This will display word count of every msg in fron of it.

**For your desired result, try this-**

```
Select `from`, sum((length(message)-length(replace(message,' ',''))+1)) as nos from table_name group by `from`
```

Comment: will you please give full query

Comment: @Steeve see the last added line, tell me if it works or not, i have not tried it yet

Comment: @Steeve first of all verify the querry yourself  and if it work properly then i will shurely explain you. There are so many books on mysql,it doesnot matter which book you prefer but it matter how much you practise yourself. Try to solve question from stacxkoverflow, that will help a lot.

Comment: @Steeve you asked for explanation and here it is. In  query `length(message)-length(replace(message,' ',''))+1` will calculate the number of word from a string and by group by and sum i am grouping table by `from` and showing sum off all words from the same `from` as you needed.

Comment: Use char_length for actual length of string in characters. Otherwise you get length in bytes and for databases with mulibyte characters you will get larger than expected values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the words are separated by a single space, you can use:

```
SUM( LENGTH(message) - LENGTH(REPLACE(message, ' ', ''))+1)
```

to get the word count. Since you want to sum all messages from each user, you'll need to group by user (from column). You should have something like this at the end:

```
select `from`, SUM( LENGTH(message) - LENGTH(REPLACE(message, ' ', ''))+1) as nos
from tableA
group by `from`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT from, SUM(LENGTH(message) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(message), ' ', ''))+1) FROM my_table GROUP BY from;
```